# What are some books for infinite dimensional linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, book-recommendation

From the linear algebra books that I've encountered, they either discuss exclusively about finite-dimensional vector spaces, or assume that the reader already knows about infinite-dimensional vector space, Hamel basis, etc.

What books explain the concept of infinite-dimensional vector space and its structures?

Comment: Hopefully someone will point out how wrong I am, but I've got the impression you should be looking for a book on *functional analysis* at that point.

Comment: I disagree with the other posters, and feel you deserve an answer to your question: there are important differences in the basic theory of linear algebra between finite and infinite dimensional vector spaces. Infinite dimensional vector spaces is theory that is worth knowing.

I recommend Chapter IX of Jacobson's Lectures in Abstract Algebra as a starting point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Infinite-dimensional vector spaces are general enough that there is not a whole lot of interesting theory about them. To get anywhere you need to make some restrictions to the subject.

Probably where you want to go is functional analysis - the study of (usually infinite-dimensional) vector spaces with topological structure. As usual, Lang has an introductory book - Real and functional analysis - that could be helpful.